# javaFX show calendar value in tableview

Tags: java, calendar, javafx, tableview, gregorian-calendar

I have the following problem.
I'm making a assignment for school, we need to show a gregoriancalendar value in a tableview.
this is my code for the table

```
TableColumn geboortedatum = new TableColumn("Geboortedatum");
    geboortedatum.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Persoon, SimpleDateFormat>("gebDat"));
```

When I actually run this I get the following value in my tableview no matter what.

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=-23574157200000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Berlin",offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=143,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Berlin,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startyear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startTime=360000
```

and it goes on like that.
anyone who has a simple solution for me? I'm probably missing something really easy here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it looks you have the wrong type for the `PropertyValueFactory`. You get away with this because you are using a raw `TableColumn`, but your code will be easier to understand if you properly type the column. From the output, I can see that your `Persoon.getGebDat()` method returns a `Calendar` object. So you should have

```
TableColumn<Persoon, Calendar> geboortedatum = new TableColumn<>("Geboortedatum");
geboortedatum.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Persoon, Calendar>("gebDat"));
```

The default behavior of a `TableCell` is to call the `toString` method of the item it is displaying. The text you are seeing is the result of calling `toString` on your `Calendar` object.

To change the way the data is displayed, you need to specify a cell factory on the `TableColumn` that creates a `TableCell` that knows how to format the `Calendar` as you want it.

So you'll do something like

```
final DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance() ; // or whatever format object you need...
geboortedatum.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<Persoon, Calendar>() {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(Calendar item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item == null) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            setText(dateFormat.format(item.getTime()));
        }
    }
});
```